# How can I implement the constructor and destructor of this set template class?

Tags: c++, constructor, set, destructor, b-tree

I am trying to implement a set template class using a B-tree (balanced tree) structure.
The private members: '''data[MAXIMUM + 1]''' has the elements of the current node in the tree.
'''set* subset[MAXIMUM + 2]''' has the pointers to the children of the current set which are also of type set. 
I am trying to implement the default constructor which supposed to create an empty set and a destructor that uses the function clear to empty the set. However, I am not understanding what should the constructor initializes and what will the destructor free. This is a code from the text: data structures -Main, Savitch 4th edition- ch12, where Savitch explains B-trees by going through the implementation of this template set. However, he does not go through the implementation of the constructor and destructor.

Here is the code:

```
template <class Item>
class set
{
public:
    // TYPEDEFS
    typedef Item value_type;
    // CONSTRUCTORS and DESTRUCTOR
    set();
    set(const set& source);
    ~set() { clear(); }
    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void operator =(const set& source);
    void clear();
    bool insert(const Item& entry);
    std::size_t erase(const Item& target);
    // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    std::size_t count(const Item& target) const;
    bool empty() const { return (data_count == 0); }
    // SUGGESTED FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING
    void print(int indent) const;
private:
    // MEMBER CONSTANTS
    static const std::size_t MINIMUM = 200;
    static const std::size_t MAXIMUM = 2 * MINIMUM;
    // MEMBER VARIABLES
    std::size_t data_count;
    Item data[MAXIMUM + 1];
    std::size_t child_count;
    set* subset[MAXIMUM + 2];
    // HELPER MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    bool is_leaf() const { return (child_count == 0); }
    bool loose_insert(const Item& entry);
    bool loose_erase(const Item& target);
    void remove_biggest(Item& removed_entry);
    void fix_excess(std::size_t i);
    void fix_shortage(std::size_t i);
```

Comment: The destructor should free everything. So if `insert` allocates something then the destructor should free that too. I would **guess** that the destructor should go through the subset array deleteing everything there. However maybe you're confused because this is bad class design IMHO. It's confusing the set (which is a tree), with the nodes that make up the tree. The `set` class here is playing both roles.

Comment: The default constructor should create a an empty set (ie. a set with 0 Items). The destructor is already implemented in the set class.

Comment: `subset` is not a good name for the array of children in a B-tree. Extremely confusing. How about `children`?

Comment: @john. I understand that the destructor should delete the pointers to the set in the member "subset". However, as for an empty set, what should the constructor allocate for subset elements? because if nothing is allocated, then what will clear() free?

Comment: Well I can't see your existing implementation but I would imagine that `data_count` tells you how many subsets you have. If you have N data items then you have N + 1 subsets. An empty set is a special case, but then if you set `data_count` to zero and `subsets[0]` to `nullptr` then I don't see any problem. But as I said I can't see your existing implementation so I can't really say for sure how you should complete it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your mind correctly, `child_count` is the count of valid entries in the `subset` array. If so, initialize it to zero in the default constructor. The destructor will need to `delete` the first `child_count` elements of `subset`.

For the data, again, if I understand you correctly, `data_count` is the count of valid entries in the `data` array. If so, you need to initialize it to 0 too. But as the `data` elements are values and not pointers, they are initialized in the constructor and finalized in the destructor automatically.

It is often better to use raw storage with all the placement new machinery to prevent creation of `MAXIMUM + 1` items even for an empty node, and also allowing `Item`s with no default constructor at all, but that requires great care to not run into UB.